# Validation Attribute messages not appearing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

```
[NumberOnly(ErrorMessage ="Should be numerics only")]
[CodeValidation(ErrorMessage="Should start with 02")]
[ValidLength(ErrorMessage="Should be of length 10 digits")]
public string Number { get; set;}
```

These validations doesn't occur, problem is, I see only two out of these validations being occurring in some machines while in other machines all occurs. Also, which two validation messages that occur is intermittent, sometime 1st two and sometime last two.

Why is it behaving like this in different machine? (In Tester machine it behaves bad like this and in my machine it works correctly ) - Same code base.

Please help me.

Comment: What are those attributes you using?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: ValidateAttribute is where I derived my attributes from. They are for a Numeric Code Number text box

Comment: Yes, but its your code - we have no idea what it is - you need to show your code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I already gave the code, attribute and error messages. Are you not able to see it please?

Comment: Can you also add HTML form code from your view to check. it is not enough just to add an atriibute. you also have to use html helper method to render that message on UI just below the control. some thing like
**Html.ValidationFor(x=> x.Number)**

Comment: @KD: Thank you, will surely paste the html, however, it works perfectly fine in my machine (Localhost). And also in one of the QA server but just not in the tester machine and few other servers where we deploy the same code base (Build). Still you want to see the code of html?

Comment: @KD: <form-error ng-form-model="code.number"></form-error>

Comment: it is a angular error , do you using angular ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
@Html.ValidationFor(model => model.Number)
```

in your view.

Comment: I couldn't see this helper anywhere in my solution, however, all error messages are being displayed in all fields in all pages. But only for this field, it is a bit weird in one or two servers but all good in other servers including localhost.